# way to switch between two internet connections

Tags: windows-7, internet, ethernet

Say you have two separate internet connections, with two separate ethernet cables. How can you switch between them automatically at time intervals, in windows 7?

Comment: if you voted this down, don't vote down questions just b/c you cant solve them!

Comment: Do you login to Win 7 with Administrator access or just have "normal User" rights?  Also, if I say "PowerShell" does it mean anything to you?

Comment: You question was down-voted (not by me) likely because it reeks of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) You give almost no details of your situation or what you are trying to accomplish. Give us the big picture of what you are trying to do and say you *think* it would be solved by switching between two internet connections at time intervals.

Answer (score 2):

If you have **Administrator access**, one way to do it is to use a **PowerShell** script and run it with **Task Scheduler**.

Typing that process with all the script code here is not something I can do right now but it already exists out there:

First, create the PowerShell script that understands the names of your two network adapters by following these instructions:

[Hey, Scripting Guy! How Can I Enable or Disable My Network Adapter?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/09/29/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-my-network-adapter.aspx)

Then, using Windows Task Scheduler, setup scheduled tasks that call the script with the desired parameters to enable and disable as needed:

[How do I set up a powershell script to run as a Scheduled Task in Windows?](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/4795/how-do-i-set-up-a-powershell-script-to-run-as-a-scheduled-task-in-windows)

If you are willing to read those two posts and experiment, you should be able to get it to work.

Comment: the second link shows how to do it between wired and wireless. how do you do it between two wired connections (two ethernet cables linked with a switch or some connector?

Comment: I beleive those are just "text names".  So in your script, you can try to hard code the real names of the Wired networks instead of the generic naming approach they used.

Comment: You have two real physical network adapters with a cable going into each one on the same machine right?  All that matters is that each adapter in Windows has its own name that you can reference in script.